# VPN set up behind Router (Windows)

Tags: windows, vpn, router

I have a computer that is connected to a basic router.

How can I set up a VPN connection that will work over the internet?

Or what do I need to set up a VPN connection behind a router?

The computer has windows.

Answer (score 1):

Most consumer routers have a PPTP (or VPN) passthrough mode that you can enable.

Other than that, most VPN clients shouldn't have much trouble connecting to a VPN service, unless your firewall is blocking those ports.